# Is there a single variable linear inequality whose only solutions are 0 and 1

Tags: inequality

In other words, is there a way to express that X is only allowed to hold the values 0 and 1 through a linear inequality?

Comment: The obvious _equation_ is $x(x-1) = 0.$ You could make an inequality out of that, I suppose, by writing $0 \leq x(x-1) \leq 0.$ Seems kind of a silly thing to do, though.

Comment: Trying to shove it into a Linear Programming problem, so I needed a way to express it through an inequality. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, the needed inequality has to be linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it depends on your domain, not on the (in)equalities.

As stated before, for linear equations on the domain of reals, it is not true, but there exists 'Integer Linear Programming' where you typically have an additional condition on the domain being integers.

Comment: Then a new problem arises where with integer linear programming (our case), the problem ends up being NP-hard, thus having no provable polynomial runtime. Thanks for helping me figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

If by `linear inequality` you mean something of the form $ax\le b$ then the answer is negative, since by continuity such a linear inequality will have a solution set that is either empty ($a=0, b \lt 0$), or an interval i.e. never a discrete, disconnected set like $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. Thank you!